# "Only support at least one signature key." when converting a tensorflow model to tensorflow lite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, speech-recognition

I have been experimenting with Tensorflow speech recognition using this notebook **running in my local machine** using a custom dataset.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio

I have successfully **trained a model and exported the model**. But when i tried to **convert the exported model to a tflite model** using the **below code** it gives me an error.

```
# Load the saved model
saved_model_path = "saved"
saved_model = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_path)

# Set the concrete function to be used for conversion
concrete_func = saved_model.signatures['serving_default']

# Convert the model to TFLite and save it in a new folder called "saved-lite"
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('saved-lite/model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

`The error : KeyError: 'serving_default'`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28532\3665239774.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # Set the concrete function to be used for conversion
----> 6 concrete_func = saved_model.signatures['serving_default']
      7 
      8 # Convert the model to TFLite and save it in a new folder called "saved-lite"

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\signature_serialization.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    245 
    246   def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 247     return self._signatures[key]
    248 
    249   def __iter__(self):
```

I **tried** to convert the model **with this code** too but it gives me an error too:

```
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('saved')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

```
ValueError: Only support at least one signature key.
```

**I use the same code provided in the tutorial notebook to export the model**. the below code

```
class ExportModel(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model

    # Accept either a string-filename or a batch of waveforms.
    # YOu could add additional signatures for a single wave, or a ragged-batch. 
    self.__call__.get_concrete_function(
        x=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string))
    self.__call__.get_concrete_function(
       x=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 16000], dtype=tf.float32))


  @tf.function
  def __call__(self, x):
    # If they pass a string, load the file and decode it. 
    if x.dtype == tf.string:
      x = tf.io.read_file(x)
      x, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(x, desired_channels=1, desired_samples=16000,)
      x = tf.squeeze(x, axis=-1)
      x = x[tf.newaxis, :]

    x = get_spectrogram(x)  
    result = self.model(x, training=False)

    class_ids = tf.argmax(result, axis=-1)
    class_names = tf.gather(label_names, class_ids)
    return {'predictions':result,
            'class_ids': class_ids,
            'class_names': class_names}

export = ExportModel(model)
```

**The model has been succesfully created and stored in the saved/ folder**. This is the **inside of the saved/ folder,**
[image]

**I'm using TensorFlow 2.11.0**

can someone correct me where I'm doing wrong, I really appreciate your help.